# how to bind multiple contents with the DataTemplate dynamically in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I want to create a TabItem with one ListBox and one WebBrowser type  contents inside it, which I want to create dynamically.
I can able to add header part correctly, but I dont know how to add multiple contents in DataTemplate.

```
       private TabItem AddTabItem()
        {
            int count = _tabItems.Count;

        TabItem tab = new TabItem();

        tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
        tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);

        WebBrowser wbr = new WebBrowser();
        wbr.MaxHeight = 1550;
        wbr.MaxWidth = 1550;
        wbr.Navigate("https://google.com");
        tab.Content = wbr;

        //Header Part is working Fine
        tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

        //I Want to add below commented line in my code for Content
        // tab.ContentTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabCont") as DataTemplate;

        return tab;
}



        <TabControl x:Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
            <!--SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged"-->
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}">
                            <Image Source="/delete.gif" Height="11" Width="11"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />

                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabCont" DataType="TabItem">

                <!-- ========================== -->
                      <!-- Bind Dynamically -->
                <!-- one list box-->
                <!-- Webbrowser-->
                <!-- ========================== -->

                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>

        </TabControl>
```

Comment: you can't add multiple contents to a data template, instead set the content to a item that does support it, eg StacKPanel, Grid, DockPanel , etc which you seem to be doing in the template about  so your question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Content property of the TabItem to a single Panel. You can then add several elements to this Panel. Which Panel you should use depends on your layout requirements. The panels have different characteristics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx.

You could for example use a DockPanel:

```
    private TabItem AddTabItem()
    {
        int count = _tabItems.Count;

        TabItem tab = new TabItem();

        tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
        tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);

        WebBrowser wbr = new WebBrowser();
        wbr.MaxHeight = 1550;
        wbr.MaxWidth = 1550;
        wbr.Navigate("https://google.com");
        DockPanel.SetDock(wbr, Dock.Bottom);

        ListBox listBox = new ListBox();

        DockPanel dockPanel = new DockPanel();
        dockPanel.Children.Add(wbr);
        dockPanel.Children.Add(listBox);
        tab.Content = dockPanel;

        tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

        return tab;
    }
```

---

```
  <TabControl x:Name="tabDynamic">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}">
                        <Image Source="/delete.gif" Height="11" Width="11"/>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

Since you want to create the elements dynamically it makes no sense to use a DataTemplate for these.